# Is there a usb controller IC which give MCU USB capability?

Tags: usb

It is disappointed that the MCU I want to use in my project does not have USB controller nor USB PHY capability. Can I simply add one standalone USB controller IC? I see device like FT2322h can translate USB to serial or parallel FIFO, is this the common way to do this job? Because it seems that I cannot achieve the full 480Mbps USB HS even using the parallel mode. Is there another better way?
Thank you!

Comment: What about to use a MCU that has this possibility?

Comment: "480 Mbps" describes the speed at which the USB PHY moves the bits of the USB protocol, not the bandwidth of your data.

Comment: What's your application? What are the communication requirements?

Comment: Forget about USB for a second. What existing I/O channel is available with your MCU that supports 480Mbps? If that is available, then that is the interface you have to use for your external USB addition. I am going to guess unless the available interface is PCIe, you are not going find any USB device for that. So your best bet is to find a MCU that meets your USB requirements in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It's just not a good idea, as the bulk of the USB protocol is implemented in software in the host MCU.  If the MCU family you're using does not support USB, chances are there's no software library for USB, and rolling your own is just Too Much Work.